# Can VBA open the newest spreadsheet by reading its name?

Tags: vba, excel

I receive a weekly Excel file from my IT department with an updated list of employees, their supervisor, department, etc. Every week, I just drag the file from the email into a designated folder on my computer.

Occasionally, I'll want a VBA script to reference and copy info from the latest version of whatever listing IT has sent to me most recently. The naming convention for the file is always the same: "EmployeeListing_20171211," but obviously with the date in the name being whatever day the file is generated. So next week, I can expect the new file to be named "EmployeeListing_20171218."

Because these files are stored in a shared folder, I have no way of knowing if other people are opening & modifying them, so I don't want the script to go by most recent Date Modified, but instead be able to read the date from the name of the file and select the file that's the newest. And all the questions I've seen related to this seem to point towards opening the file that has the most recent Date Modified, not in whose *name* includes the most recent date.

To do this, it seems to me like I need to read in the names of all the files in the folder, tell VBA how to convert the string to a date, find the date that's the most recent, and then find the corresponding Excel file that matches this date. But I have no idea where to start. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: yes, search for DIR function

Comment: The `right` function returns x characters from the right of the string. `Mid` chops out pieces of a string. `msgbox #2017/12/13#` shows basic recognises that format but it requires delimiters.

Comment: If all files start with `EmployeeListing_`, you dn't have to analyse the date: You can simply order the filenames alphabetically, and the newest file will have the 'largest' filename ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code with comments that will get you started.

```
Sub test()

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtFile As Date
    Dim dtMax As Date, sMax As String
    Dim sDate As String

    'Folder where your files live
    sPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\MyFolder\"

    'Get the first file that starts with EmployeeListing_
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "EmployeeListing_*")

    'If there are no files, the lenght = 0
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        sDate = Split(sFile, "_")(1) 'get the date part of the file name

        'turn it into an actual date
        dtFile = DateSerial(Left$(sDate, 4), Mid$(sDate, 5, 2), Mid(sDate, 7, 2))

        'if it's bigger than any others, store the date and name
        If dtFile > dtMax Then
            dtMax = dtFile
            sMax = sFile
        End If
        'no arguments means get the next file using the same arguments as
        'previosly supplied
        sFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Print the file with the biggest date
    Debug.Print sPath & sMax

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great - thanks, @Dick Kusleika! Very helpful starting point